Book title 'Money' in Martin Amis's 'Money'
In Martin Amis's book Money, published in 1984, the narrator, John Self, refers several times to a book he is reading called Money. Is the latter supposed to be a real book?

Everything in this book is called money. The film is called Money. There are characters called Money. The word money appears on every page,  often multiple times.

Some other books Self reads are real. I just wondered whether 'Money' is. I suspect not. It may be a weird form of self-reference. Another example is that Martin Amis is a significant character in the book.

There are of course many books called Money, possibly the best-known being the novel by Emile Zola. There is even the possibility, given the self-referential nature of the narrative, that the character J. Self is reading Amis' book itself. However, I think that enough information is spread out along the novel to actually identify the work as John Kenneth Galbraith's weighty history of money, entitled Money: Whence It Came, Where It Went.
Self was given Money by Martina, "Martina gave me Money, and
several other books: Freud, Marx, Darwin, Einstein and Hitler.", and he dips in and out of it along the course of the novel. Towards the end of the novel we are told:

I was drinking scotch and  reading Money… I cross-checked with the
index of Money. Ricardo, Gresham, Biddle,  Baruch.

so this is a book with an index. Rather than being a novel it sounds like being more like a scholarly work, an impression that is backed up by Self musing:

Money gives me panic attacks, even when the guy is  going on about
Italian banking or the birth of American corporations. I don't know
why.

So it seems to be  a work specifically about the history of money. This cuts the field of candidates down substantially, and Galbraith's work indeed mentions Bernard Baruch, Francis Biddle, David Ricardo, and Thomas Gresham in the index, as well as discussing the history of Italian banking and the birth of American corporations.
We are given some more specific information about the contents of the book:

Money is full of interesting things. Bad money drives out  good money,
for example. Gresham's Law. The embossing of monarchs' heads on the
surface of coins was an ego-gimmick dreamed up by the rulers. When
Caligula finally checked out they melted down the entire currency to
wipe his  face off the loathed dough. You know, they used to use meat
for money, and snout, and booze, and chicks of course

Gresham's law is well-known, and should be mentioned in most works about money. Galbraith introduces the topic with:

the enduring observation of Sir Thomas Gresham, previously made by
Oresme and Copernicus and reflected in the hoarding of the good Roman
coin, that bad money always drives out good.

He also mentions the next point, about "the embossing of monarchs' heads" on coins as a point of vanity:

After Alexander the Great the custom was established of depicting the
head of the sovereign on the coin, less, it has been suggested, as a
guarantee of the weight and fineness of the metal than as a thoughtful
personal gesture by the ruler to himself.

and also the more obscure anecdote about Caligula:

According to Suetonius, after the death of Caligula his money was
called in and melted down so that not only the name but the features
of the tyrant might be forgotten.

Galbraith also discusses the use of meat, "snout" (tobacco), and "booze" as forms of currency not based on precious metals:

And much later tobacco, as will be told, had a limited but notable
run. More awkward or exotic items such as cattle, shells,
whiskey and stones...
there were numerous lesser experiments with grain, cattle, whiskey and
brandy, all of which at one time or another were declared legal tender
for debts.

(the "as will be told" story of tobacco was the use of cigarettes as currency  in Germany after the Second World War).
The final item mentioned, "chicks" (young women), is also discussed:

All the young women of Lydia prostitute themselves, by which they
procure their marriage portion; this, with their persons, they
afterwards dispose of as they think proper

Galbraith's book was published in 1965, which is consistent with it being available in Money, published in 1984. This, together with the rather specific details we are given about the contents, leads me to believe that we can positively identify the book in question as Galbraith's history.
